# Finding the actual max_depth of each tree in HistGradientBoostRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

for a random forest regressor, i can find the actual max_depth reached by each tree using:

```py
max_depth = list()
for tree in rf.estimators_:
    max_depth.append(tree.tree_.max_depth)
```

Is there a way to do this with a HistGradientBoost Regressor? It doesn't have the estimators_ attribute.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[72], line 29
     27 print(f'number of trees per iteration: {hgb.n_trees_per_iteration_} ')
     28 max_depth = list()
---> 29 for tree in hgb.estimators_:
     30     max_depth.append(tree.tree_.max_depth)
     32 print("avg max depth %0.1f" % (sum(max_depth) / len(max_depth)))

AttributeError: 'HistGradientBoostingRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators_'
```